# bash inside applescript inside python3 return value

Tags: bash, macos, apache, python-3.x

I am working on a control panel for the inbuilt apache server in OSX/macOS
and am trying to do a check of the status of the server - wether it is running or not. In mac there is no actual single command to check if the server is running through httpd/apachectl (I am using the latter). So I am trying to check by starting the server and then if it gives a return value of 'all good' (or in `os.system()`'s case, `0`) then turn it off again and say it wasn't running, or if it returned an error, say it was already running. Basically I need to get the return value of the bash I am executing inside applescript, and that return value goes into the rest of my python script. This is what I have so far:

```
status = os.system('''
    osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo apachectl start" with administrator privileges'
''')

if (status == 0):
    os.system('''
        osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo apachectl stop" with administrator privileges'
    ''')
    statusText.config(state=NORMAL)
    statusText.insert(END, "Not Running")
    statusText.config(state=DISABLED, fg="red")
else:
    statusText.config(state=NORMAL)
    statusText.insert(END, "Running")
    statusText.config(state=DISABLED, fg="green")
```

I intend to make this a standalone application, so I need all built-ins.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend using a more pythonic means like `subprocess()` and why not query `apachectl status` instead of starting or stopping the service to get the result?

Comment: @l'L'l On mac apachectl status returns this: `Go to http://localhost:80/server-status in the web browser of your choice.
Note that mod_status must be enabled for this to work.`

Comment: Ah, okay that makes more sense. Well, I guess you could likely grep `ps` perhaps as your `status` since it outputs whether or not there's an active pid of `httpd`... What module is statusText derived from?

Comment: @l'L'l statusText is a tkinter text widget

Comment: @l'L'l what do you mean by grep? Sorry, I am not experienced in bash